# How can I improve this code for non-prime numbers?

Tags: python, numbers

I have written a code for displaying whether the given number is prime or not. It is displaying if the number is prime but it gets stuck if the number is not prime.
**This it the code:**

```
a = 2
factors = []
while a <= i:
    if i % a == 0:
        factors.append(a)
        continue
    if len(factors) == 1 and factors[0] == i:
        print("The given number " + str(i) + " is a prime number")
        break
    else:
        factors.clear()
    a += 1
```

Please help me.

Comment: okay, but nevertheless i got the solution by myself

Comment: You never break out of your loop if 'i' isn't prime.  You'll continue incrementing `a` forever.

Comment: what is `i`'s value?